# Android url get file fail

Tags: java, android, url

I've got a url:

```
http://www.mubie.com/sites/default/files/imageifarm/紫薇.jpg
```

now, if I try to get the file:

```
String url = "http://www.mubie.com/sites/default/files/imageifarm/紫薇.jpg"; //url is a string
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url).getContent());
```

it throws the following exception:

```
09-23 17:10:57.812: W/System.err(2059): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.mubie.com/sites/default/files/imageifarm/紫薇.jpg
09-23 17:10:57.812: W/System.err(2059):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
09-23 17:10:57.812: W/System.err(2059):     at java.net.URLConnection$DefaultContentHandler.getContent(URLConnection.java:1042)
09-23 17:10:57.812: W/System.err(2059):     at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:203)
09-23 17:10:57.812: W/System.err(2059):     at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:447)
09-23 17:10:57.822: W/System.err(2059):     at com.sora.insync.demo.ViewQuestion.loadImageFromNetwork(ViewQuestion.java:273)
```

how can i solve this issue? convert the chinese characters to unicode?

**The url(and the file) is perfectly valid**

what i've tried

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(URLEncoder.encode(url,
                "UTF8")).getContent());
```

but it turns the url into something like:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mubie.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fimageifarm%2F%E7%B4%AB%E8%96%87.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, your code is failing on the Chinese characters. You should call `toASCIIString()` on your URL-string:

```
InputStream stream = (InputStream) new URL(url).toASCIIString().getContent();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
```

Comment: the url is a string, please edit your answer :`new URI(url).toASCIIString()`